# About zero-padding for the FFT in the Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, zero-padding

I have a question about the zero-padding for the `fft`. I ran `fft` with zero-padding & without zero-padding and compared.

```
sf = 100; %sampling frequency
dt=1/sf; %time sampling interval
L = 10; %Length of signal
t = linspace(0,L,L/dt+1);

%zero-padding
nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(t)); %expansion of the data length for fft
t(length(t)+1:nfft) = 0; L = dt*nfft; t = linspace(0,L,L/dt+1);
t(end)=[];

fr = 4; %frequency
data = cos(2*pi*fr1*t);
df = sf/length(data); %frequency increment
f = (0:length(data)/2)*df;
fft_result =fft(data)/length(data);
spec_fft = 2*abs(fft_result); %spectrum
pha_fft = angle(fft_result); %phase
pha_fft = rad2deg(pha_fft);

subplot(2,1,1);
stem(f,spec_fft(1:length(f)));
subplot(2,1,2);
stem(f,pha_fft(1:length(f)));
```

And I could see the difference between the two result images.
[image]

[image]

When I did `fft` without zero-padding, the amplitude was displayed clear, and the phase also clear (I think other frequencies' phase is due to a very small amplitude value not zero). But When I used zero-padding, I could see amplitudes of nearby frequency that I input(4Hz) show different aspects and the result of the phase is strange in my opinion. Is there some problem in my code when I used zero-padding?

*Additional question for comments of Cris Luengo

I tried to pad zeros to the data by the extended length.

```
nfft = 2^nextpow2(length(t)); %expansion of the data length for fft
data(length(t)+1:nfft) = 0;
```

When I plot the data, I got
[image]
As you can see, values over 10 are zeros.

And I got this result.
[image]

I wonder whether my results are okay or not.

Comment: You zero-pad `t`, and then create a whole new `t`. Then you generate your signal of the same length, you don’t zero-pad it.

Comment: Also, note how the amplitude of the frequencies is mostly zero in the padded case, there is no meaning for the spectral phase for epsilon amplitude frequencies.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks for your answer. But actually, I already tried to pad zeros to the data, it showed a more strange result. I will edit my question, please check my other result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the FFT magnitude result is close to zero, it might just be numerical noise (random quantization and rounding errors).  The phase of this numerical noise is nonsense.  I usually set the phase to zero unless the corresponding magnitude is above some threshold for actual non-zero spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you phase has strange result because of the frequency leakage (frequency leakage not only affect the magnitude, also greatly affect the phase estimation)

You can check to estimate the phase of sin(10Hz) by FFT

```
Fs = 100;
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
N = 100;              % Length of signal
t = (0:N-1)*T;        % Time vector

Fs = 100;
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
N = 70;               % Length of signal
t = (0:N-1)*T;        % Time vector
```